# Issue in using a .lib in a VS2008/VC project

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, static-libraries, visual-c++

I wanted to learn how to use a .lib file in my C application.

So, I followed these steps:

1. Created a empty project in VC++,
2. Added a .c file,
3. Added few c functions,
4. Created a .h file for the same,
5. Changed the projects type to .lib
6. Built the project.

No problem till here.

Now,

7. I copied the .h and the .lib file to desktop,
8. created another VC++ empty project of type .exe,
9. In poject prop.->config. prop.->c/c++->additional include directories,I added the path to desktop,
10. In poject prop.->config. prop.->linker->additional library dependencies,I added the path to desktop,
11. building the project gives `LNK2019 (unresolved external symbol _...)` and `fatal error LNK1120 (unresolved external symbols)`.

What am I doing wrong? Also what would be the steps to use a .dll instead of .lib?

Configuration: Windows 7, VS2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to add the library by name to the list of Additional Dependencies in Linker->Input options for your Project.

Do you really want this linked in from the desktop, by the way?  Typically some project-relative path or environment variable would be the way to do this - you do not want to link from desktop on a build server, for example.

Switching to a DLL will not help because you still need to use the export library (.LIB) file for your DLL to satisfy the link-time dependencies.

Comment: no,it's just a quick walk through for me, OK I want the .lib files in a /lib directory relative to the .exe and .h file in a /headers directory...so what do you suggest.?

Comment: Your project already has a `$(OutputDir)` default (under Project properties, Configuration Properties->General) - you could just use that location as the input to the next build, that uses the .lib file. Or define a `PostBuild Event` (Project Properties->Build Events) on the Library build which copies the .Lib file to the place you want on successful build.

Comment: oh sorry I(newbie) got confused between the concepts of a dll and a lib that a lib is needed only for building the exe once and dll always needed as it is not a part of the exe right???

Comment: Almost.  You can build your library either as a static library, or as a DLL.  In the static case, the Lib file contains all required code.  in the DLL case, it contains just export information to allow link to work, and the code lives in the DLL.  Either way, you usually link your library user application using a .Lib file. Unless you want to manually load the DLL and work out where the functions are you want to call.

Comment: Thanks man,I'll disturb you once more...you said we can use a dll file in an app without the need of a lib file, could you shed more light on how can i do that?I'm getting a hint of the 'LoadLibray' win32 func.But linux does'nt have that...then what?